# Why InstallShield does not use the assembly processed after post build event?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I have a .net project that has a post build event to apply a signature to the final assembly. But InstallShield is not getting the signed assembly. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You might want to provide more information about how the post-build event finds the assembly, where it puts the signed output (if it differs), and how InstallShield finds the assembly.

Comment: I has a developer having the same problem. We are using ildasm and ilasm to apply the key. It is a temporary solution for now, but it is still causing a great deal of headaches for us.

Answer (score 0):

The limited edition is removing the digital signature.

IF you want the exe to be signed you need to have paid version and select "Include files and patterns" of the signing tab.